# Datagrip connecting to databases on launch

Tags: mysql, connections, datagrip

I'm using Jetbrains Datagrip to connect to Mysql servers. My problem is that Datagrip connects to the various databases I created as soon as I launch it. That's not a problem with development databases, but I really don't want that for production databases. Is the a way to indicate to Datagrip I want it to connect to production databases only when I say so?

Comment: How do you detect that that the actual connection happens?

Comment: There is a small green dot beside the database logo.

Comment: Do you mean, DataGrip tries to reconnect to databases when you start (restart) IDE?

Comment: @Vasili In the meantime, I was able to check that DataGrip only connected to the database when I tried to access it.

Comment: @AlexisDufrenoy , so, the question is answered then?

Comment: @VasiliiChernov Yes.